# Image anchor doesn't work, adding display block doesn't work either

Tags: html, css

I have a page like this http://codepen.io/meek/pen/NNprYb?editors=1000
In the portfolio section, I'm trying to add an anchor to the images. But clicking them doesn't seem to trigger the new window.

The html looks like:

```
<a href="http://google.com" target="_blank">
    <img src="img/portfolio/pomodoro.jpg" />
</a>
```

I've also tried:

```
<a href="http://google.com" target="_blank">
    <img src="img/portfolio/pomodoro.jpg">
</a>
```

(no self closing tags)

and

```
<a href="http://google.com" target="_blank" style="display:block;">
    <img src="img/portfolio/pomodoro.jpg">
</a>
```

and none of these methods work.

Comment: In your codepen you have the links inside of the figure tag, try nesting the figure inside of the anchor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your overlay, `.tint:before`, is covering up the clickable area of the `a` tag. Moving the `a` tag out side of the `figure` tag should make it clickable. I'm not sure how it would affect the CSS though.

Comment: Don't know how I didn't think of this. It works perfectly, thank you!